# Can you fetch_assoc() after an INSERT query?

Tags: php, mysqli

Can you fetch the assoc from a query straight after an INSERT query?

e.g.

```
$Password =  crypt("password");
$Query = $db->query("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('Connor', '{$Password}')");
echo $Query->fetch_assoc()["user_id"]; // user_id is auto_incremented in the table
```

Comment: why use fetch if you have that value

Comment: for caching, I though of having a cache decorator and to have the same behavior for both insert queries and select queries (with 1 minute expiration) so both select and insert queries will use my cache and not my mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) — Fetch a result row as an associative array

Your query has to be a select query so that result can be fetched.

Answer (score 2):

When you execute the `INSERT` query, you will get `BOOL` depending on if query executed or not. It will not return a result set which can be traversed using `fetch_assoc()` function.

`query()` function returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries, it will return a result object. For other successful queries `query()` will return TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

No. The `$Query` you provided simply updates the database, it doesn't make it available to fetch_assoc(). I would suggest doing the following in the line immediately after `$Query`.

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
```

Then fetch_assoc() from $sql.